Question Regarding proof of limsupXn is a random variable
Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ be a measurable space. If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables and I want to prove $\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n$ is a random variable. This is to show that
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\{w\in\Omega:\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n(w)<x\}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$$
One solution is that
$$ \{ w\in\Omega:\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n(w)<x \}=\bigcap_{m>0}\bigcup_{n>0}\bigcap_{k>n}\{w\in\Omega:X_k(w)\le x-1/m \}$$
I understand the inner intersection and middle union, but confusing about the outer union. My thought is that we can convert open interval to half interval: $(-\infty, x)=\bigcup_{m>0}(-\infty, x-1/m]$ so that it make sense for me if the outer intersection to be union.
